# PostgreSQL: add_column "after" option usage in Rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, hash, database-migration

I'm trying to add a new column, 'latitude', to an existing Postgres table, after the 'location' column.

Using this syntax puts the column in the correct place:

```
add_column :table, :column, :decimal, :after => :existing_column
```

And using this syntax ensures that the field is the correct data type

```
add_column :table, :column, :decimal, {:precision => 10, :scale => 6}
```

But when I try and combine the two:

```
add_column :table, :column, :decimal, {:precision => 10, :scale => 6}, :after => :existing_column
```

I get "ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (5 for 3..4)"

"Not to worry", I thought, "I'll just combine the arguements!":

```
add_column :table, :column, :decimal, {:precision => 10, :scale => 6, :after => :existing_column}
```

But then the columns appear at the end of the table. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks :)

Comment: [The order of the columns is totally irrelevant in relational databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243547/how-to-add-a-new-column-in-a-table-after-the-2nd-or-3rd-column-in-the-table-usin)

Comment: Yep I'm aware of that, but I kind of like keeping related things together just from a sanity point of view...

Comment: in `add_column` method no  such option `:after => :existing_column`. allowed options you can find in [documentation for this method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_column#637-Options)

Comment: @Зелёный there is such option. I used it in my Rails 3.1 project with MySQL and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov show me documentation please for this option.

Comment: @Зелёный I can't see available options in documentation(you reference is not on documentation either), but I can say it for sure because I used it. [Check the relevant SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15481778/644810) and [one more](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8336005/644810)

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov ok, my bad, i use only `pg` and never `mysql`. +1 for hidden feature.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your last definition is correct. But the problem here isn't with Rails, but with PostgreSQL, which doesn't allow to add a column at specific position. Read more: [How can I specify the position for a new column in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3276/how-can-i-specify-the-position-for-a-new-column-in-postgresql)

Comment: Ah, silly me, I'd not tested the :after option since moving from MYSQL to Postgres. Good catch, thanks :)